# c# get html response after script application

Tags: c#, html, output

I want to have the result of html page but after application of the javascript.
If you prefere what i need is to have the html output and not the page code.

Seems not to so easy ?

Comment: Two words: browser automation.

Comment: If you are using WebBrowserControl then you can use its DocumentText property.

Answer (score 0):

try
{

```
        string Url = BaseUrl + "#_tabVideos,page-" + Count.ToString();

        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.AddArguments("profile-directory=Default");
        options.AddArguments("--ignore-certificate-errors", "--ignore-ssl-errors");
        options.AddArguments("--headless");
        options.AddArgument("--disable-in-process-stack-traces");
        options.AddArgument("--disable-logging");
        //options.AddArgument("--log-level=ALLL");
        options.AddArgument("--log-level=ERROR");
        //options.AddArgument("--no-sandbox");
        options.AddArgument("--disable-extensions");
        options.AddArguments("--no-sandbox");
        options.AddArguments("--disable-infobars");
        options.AddArguments("--disable-dev-shm-usage");
        options.AddArguments("--disable-browser-side-navigation");
        options.AddArguments("--disable-gpu");
        String stDate = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
        options.AddArguments(@"user-data-dir=" + @"d:\tmp\BrowseVideoX\" );
        //IWebDriver CrDriver = new ChromeDriver(@"C:\Users\serge viardot\Downloads\chromedriver_win32(1)", options);
        //IWebDriver CrDriver = new ChromeDriver(Application.ExecutablePath.Replace("SexCrawler.exe",string.Empty),options);
        IWebDriver CrDriver = new ChromeDriver(@"D:\Users\serge viardot\Source\Repos\SexBrowse2\chromedriver_win32", options, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(3));
        CrDriver.Manage().Timeouts().PageLoad.Add(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10));
        CrDriver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait.Add(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10));
        CrDriver.Navigate().GoToUrl(Url);
        string Results = CrDriver.FindElement(By.TagName("body")).Text;
        //Get list of web-elements with tagName  - a
        foreach (IWebElement item in CrDriver.FindElements(By.TagName("a")))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item.GetAttribute("href"));
            if (item.GetAttribute("href")!=null)
                Liens.Add(item.GetAttribute("href"));
        }
        CrDriver.Dispose();
        Console.WriteLine(Results);

        if (Results.Contains("Loading failed.") || Results.Contains("Echec du chargement"))
            bContinue = false;
         Count++;
    }
    catch (Exception Ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Ex.Message + " " + Ex.Source);
    }
}
```